# Total Cost of PAYE?

Tags: united-states, student-loan, refinance

I'm evaluating my options for my Federal Loan debt, namely continue with PAYE or refinance with a private lender. Presently I'm enjoying deferment until Jan, 2022 due to President Biden's decision.

Anyway, I have $400,000 in debt at 6.8% APR. With Pay As You Earn (PAYE), I have 120 (10 years of) payments left before my balance is forgiven. By forgiven, I mean that the loan will expire, yet the balance will become my taxable income. So, if there's $200,000 left in the loan after 120 payments, I'll have +$200,000 in taxable income. Presently I earn $300,000 annually.

I do not know how to calculate the total cost if I continue with PAYE. Of course it's trivial for me to calculate the total cost via refinancing.

Please help me with this math. I looked at calculators like this one, https://studentloanhero.com/calculators/pay-as-you-earn-calculator/, however it operates over 20 years, whereas I only have 10 years left.